# Thread Safe Copying of Objects in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I have a static array of classes similar to the following:

```
public class Entry {
    private String sharedvariable1= "";
    private String sharedvariable2= "";
    private int sharedvariable3= -1;

    private int mutablevariable1 = -1
    private int mutablevariable2 = -2;

    public Entry (String sharedvariable1, 
                  String sharedvariable2, 
                  int sharedvariable3) {
        this.sharedvariable1 = sharedvariable1;
        this.sharedvariable2 = sharedvariable2;
        this.sharedvariable3 = sharedvariable 3;
    }

    public Entry (Entry entry) {  //copy constructor. 
        this (entry.getSharedvariable1, 
              entry.getSharedvariable2, 
              entry.getSharedvaraible3);
    }
....
/* other methods including getters and setters*/
}
```

At some point in my program I access an instance of this object and make a copy of it using the copy constructor above.    I then change the value of the two mutable variables above.   This program is running in a multithreaded environment.   **Please note.  ALL VARIABLES ARE SET WITH THEIR INITIAL VALUES PRIOR TO THREADING.**   Only after the program is threaded an a copy is made, are the variables changed.       I believe that it is thread safe because I am only reading the static object, not writing to it (even shared variable3, although an int and mutable is only read) and I am only making changes to the copy of the static object (and the copy is being made within a thread).    But, I want to confirm that my thinking is correct here.

Can someone please evaluate what I am doing?

Comment: I would make the immutable fields `final` to make it clear they don't change.  This could also improve thread safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it is thread safe under the conditions outlined since I am only reading from the variables in their static state and only changing the copies.

Comment: Reading again what type is what.. so delete/add.

the strings are actually the same objects(not a copy). the integers are not.
it doesn't matter if you only read and never change the other though.

oh and synchronizing too big areas is bad(easier deadlocks, too long waits etc), so just try to think where it might be changed at the same time as read.

and for the answer above this, the strings don't need sync because they're immutables(if you want a mutable string, use stringbuffer etc). the ints might not have the latest state(but if not changed anywhere, then it is the latest state)

Answer (score 3):

It is not thread-safe.  You need to wrap anything that *modifies* the sharedvariables thusly:

```
synchronized (this) {
    this.sharedvariable1 = newValue;
}
```

For setters, you can do this instead:

```
public synchronized void setSharedvariable1(String sharedvariable1) {
    this.sharedvariable1 = sharedvariable1;
}
```

Then in your copy constructor, you'll do similarly:

```
public Entry (Entry entry) {
    this();
    synchronized(entry) {
        this.setSharedvariable1(entry.getSharedvariable1());
        this.setSharedvariable2(entry.getSharedvariable2());
        this.setSharedvariable3(entry.getSharedvariable3());
    }
}
```

This ensures that if modifications are being made to an instance, the copy operation will wait until the modifications are done.

Comment: Also if OP (or whoever modifies his code in the future) ever modifies that static array... that's a huge potential thread safety issue.

Comment: You can't have a constructor built as above.   Java doesn't like that.   The

Comment: @Elliott, you're right.  I've modified the constructor so it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not thread-safe, you should synchronize in your copy constructor. You are reading each of the three variables from the original object in your copy constructor. These operations are not atomic together. So it could be that while you are reading the first value the third value gets changed by another thread. In this case you have a "copied" object in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

It's not thread safe. And I mean that is does not **guarantee** thread safety for multiple threads that use the same `Entry` instance.

The problem I see here is as follows:

1. `Thread 1` starts constructing an `Entry` instance. It does not keep that instance hidden from other threads access.
2. `Thread 2` accesses that instance, using its copy constructor, while it is still in the middle of construction.

Considering the initial value for `Entry`'s field `private int sharedvariable3= -1;`, the result might be that the new "copied" instance created by `Thread 2` will have its `sharedvariable3` field set to `0` (the default for int class fields in java).

That's the problem.

If it bothers you, you've got to either `synchronize` the read/write operations, or take care of `Entry` instances publication. Meaning, don't allow access of other threads to an `Entry` instance that is in the middle of construction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get, why you consider private instance variables as shared. Usually shared fields are static and not private - I recommend you not to share private instance variables. For thread-safety you should synchronize the operations that mutate the variables values.

You can use the synchronized keyword for that but choose the correct monitor object (I think the entry itself should do). Another alternative is to use some lock implementation from java.util.concurrent. Usually locks offer higher throughput and better granularity (for example multiple parallel reads but only one write at any given time).

Another thing you have to think about is what is called the memory barrier. Have a look at this interesting article http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-memory-model-programer%E2%80%99s

You can enforce the happens before semantic with the volatile keyword. Explicit synchronization (locks or synchonized code) also crosses the memory barrier and enforces happens before semantics.

Finally a general piece of advice: You should avoid shared mutable state at all costs. Synchronization is a pain in the ass (performance and maintenance wise). Bugs that result from incorrect synchronization are incredibly hard to detect. It is better to design for immutability or isolated mutability (e.g. actors).

Comment: sure, if you have unlimited computing resources. but then why bother.

an actor pattern might complicate a simple task to being quite complicated and expensive cpu/memory wise.